# Preposition before infinitive - a vs da

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I found the following sentence:

> È un vero peccato che ti abbiano rubato il portafoglio.
>
> Ora non possiamo comprare da mangiare.

However, I wonder why this uses `comprare da mangiare`, instead of `comprare a mangiare`. I know both `a` and `da` can be used as a proposition before an infinitive verb. I also know that there is a usage of `da + infinitive` to express "something to do" much like `to + infinitive` in English.

However, then I wonder why `da mangiare` can work without an object. For example, if the sentence is the following, which has an object to modify, I have no problem in understanding it:

> Ora non possiamo comprare qualcosa da mangiare.

However, if there is no object there, I can't differentiate when to use `a` and when to use `da`, especially since both can be used to express an aim after the main verb.

So how can I tell apart the use cases of these two prepositions?

(Please answer the question in English if possible...)

Comment: I'd say that “comprare da mangiare” has an implicit “qualcosa” in the middle, so “da mangiare” becomes a noun phrase.

Comment: @egreg I see. Then is there any other similar verbs like that, which has an implicit "qualcosa" to modify? Also, then do I have to memorize these verbs one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/da/), *da* may introduce a final clause when after a verb:

> 4. Con verbi, introduce proposizioni finali o consecutive: *dammi un libro da leggere*; *non hanno da mangiare*; *Forse s’avess’io l’ale // Da volar su le nubi* (Leopardi); *facevano un rumore tale da sbalordire*; *non ho niente da fare*; *guadagna tanto da vivere*; *non c’è tempo da perdere*, ecc. Usi più particolari: *far da mangiare*; *negozio da affittare*; *uomo da ammirare* (= degno di essere ammirato); *c’è da essere investiti*, o *da farsi investire, con questo traffico*; *c’è da diventar matti*; *avere da*, dovere: *ho da fare*, *ho molto da scrivere*, *ho da correre subito alla stazione*.

In my opinion you can think to it also as a “noun phrase”, so *da mangiare* is *qualcosa da mangiare*, and the doubt should vanish.